# What species of butterfly is this?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

This big fellow came to visit my kitchen (in Hong Kong) a bit earlier.
It is brown with some longitudinal white stripes, banana/boomerang-shaped patterns towards the middle, and an eye-like marking on each forewing tip. Picture below.
What kind of butterfly is it?

[image: butterfly]

I helped it find the exit in the meantime, not before taking a lot more pictures.

Comment: Can you please add where your kitchen is located?

Comment: People can't search by image very easily. Could you please add a text description of it to help people find it?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I'm not sure how to describe it.. brown butterfly (well.. moth) with white stripes? Any suggestions?

Comment: @aditsu, something like that is good. The marking on the front tip of the wing looks a little like an eye too. I'd describe some of the other markings as boomerang or banana shaped, and v-shaped.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I added a description, you can suggest changes if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't a butterfly, it's a saturnid moth -  [*Samia canningi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samia_canningi), also known as the wild eri silkworm moth.

There is a good image on Flickr [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/thomascalame/8407970246/), and some more information [here](http://www.saturniidae-web.de/Samia%20canningi.htm).

Comment: Oh wow, something about its coloring and behavior seemed to say "moth", but I couldn't believe that a moth could be so big and so beautiful.

Comment: It's related to the largest sprcies of moth - the Atlas moth.

Comment: A lot of those Samia look alike, I'm impressed that you could identify the exact one.